# Crash in Jetpack Compose version 2022.12.00

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is happening only on Samsung Galaxy Tab A devices. I don't know what triggers it because there in not enough information in the stack trace. Has anyone seen this?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Padding must be non-negative
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValuesModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:404)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1077)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1073)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:107)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.java:1073)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.java:36)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:341)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:320)
       at androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:242)
       at androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1$measure$1.placeChildren(SubcomposeLayout.kt:603)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:275)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:77)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.java:930)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:137)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:445)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:450)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:92)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:427)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:445)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.java:223)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:186)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:125)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:275)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:77)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.java:930)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:137)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer(Placeable.kt:468)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer$default(Placeable.kt:286)
       at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:407)
       at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:406)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:202)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:445)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:450)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:92)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:427)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:445)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.java:223)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:186)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:125)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:275)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:77)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.java:930)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:137)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer(Placeable.kt:468)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer$default(Placeable.kt:286)
       at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:407)
       at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:406)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:202)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative(Placeable.kt:434)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative$default(Placeable.kt:199)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:663)
       at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:662)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:202)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer-aW-9-wM(Placeable.kt:471)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:452)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:92)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:427)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelativeWithLayer(Placeable.kt:460)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelativeWithLayer$default(Placeable.kt:266)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy$measure$2.invoke(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:43)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy$measure$2.invoke(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:39)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:275)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:77)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.java:930)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:137)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:445)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:450)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:341)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:92)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:427)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.java:35)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative(Placeable.kt:434)
       at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative$default(Placeable.kt:199)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.place$ui_release(LayoutNode.java:802)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:443)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:39)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:330)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:869)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17794)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnLayout$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:320)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onLayout(ComposeView.android.kt:311)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17794)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17794)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17794)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:727)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17794)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2353)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2075)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1261)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6345)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6138)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
```

Answer (score 1):

Padding must be non-negative:

```
Modifier.padding(value)  // value >= 0.dp
```

Comment: The question is how did it become negative?

Comment: What about your code?